# Filter email id's before sending from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sendgrid, codeigniter-hooks

I have to filter email id's before sending through Codeigniter's

```
$this->email->to($userEmailIds);
```

function. I have thinking to do like It is possible to do with Codeigniter's Hooks functionality. I am not sure because never used codeigniter hooks functionality just hear and read something about that. Please if anyone implement this type of functionality then help me. Otherwise my last option is thinking about filter from Codeigniter's core system files. My main intention is filter `null@null.com` which sending from our product and issues is that we have lot's of places in product where we implement send email functionality. So i think it is not a good idea to checking at all places.

Also Just for information we have used **sendgrid** in our product and that's why we know that from our system we are sending `null@null.com` emails.

Comment: You should validate the e-mail addresses before you store them in your database...

Comment: @jeroen, you are right but the product is very big and now to do any code at all places it's more time consuming. So that's why I need any global filter solution if it is possible.

Comment: So? How hard can it be to write a script that cleans up the invalid e-mail addresses once and for all? All the more reason to do that if the system is big; you should solve the problem instead of working around it.

Comment: @jeroen, Yeah, but issue is that I am not only the developer who worked on that more people also working. If suppose I will clean up invalid email and then again from where it should inserted or someone write new script which causes the same issues which send null@null.com then what? We should not setup cronjob like for that to cleanup invalid emails daily.